# Embed an MP3 music file onto an image

Tags: html, mp3, embed, audio

Good afternoon,

I have am image and I want to embed the MP3 file associated with the image into/onto the image, instead of having the MP3 under the image.

Is this at all possible.

Kind regards

Gary

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="Logoghp.jpg" width="224" height="134" alt=""/><br>
<audio controls>
  <embed src="Soul Train Easter 2016 Mke Vitti One Hour Mix Show.mp3" width="32" height="32"></embed>
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want the audio controls to be inside the image?

Comment: use javascript onclick event in img tag and create function for audio play

Answer (score 0):

Create a "container" `div` and, inside it, insert your image and an [`audio` element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) (containing at least a `source` and a warning message for browsers that don't support it).

Give the "container" the same height of the image, assign the `audio` element "relative" [`position`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp), then play with `top` and `left` values, *e.g.*:

```css
.audio-container {
  height: 320px;
}
.audio-container audio {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-container">
  <img src="http://www.battiato.it/wp-content/themes/battiato/images/about.jpg">
  <br>
  <audio controls>
    <source src="http://www.battiato.it/wp-content/uploads/mp3/joe/1-leoncavallo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>
```