# Opening a new tab with an mp3 file and an image with one hyperlink

Tags: php, html

I'm new to html coding and need some advice.  I have a php file that loads an mp3 file to a new page and works flawlessly however, I would like to add an image with the audio player so it loads both on the new page.

The website is bilingual (English & Spanish) which means one side of the website is written in English only and the other side of the website is written in Spanish only.  The script is written to show the correct language and play the correct mp3 audio file (English or Spanish) according to the language of the site a person is visiting.  The script uses a MYSQL database to accomplish this task for the hyperlink (includes text and a date) which means if a person is on the Spanish side of the website the hyperlink appears in Spanish same goes for English side of the website.  Each week, I load two new mp3 files (English & Spanish) and link them to the Spanish or English text with a date in the database.  Once the hyperlink is clicked, it opens the mp3 file in a new page and it works great.  I would like to add an image so that the mp3 player and image open in the same page but not sure how to incorporated it into my existing php file.  The image is located in the following location - src='images/pictures/wmbvog.jpg'

The php file is written as follows.

```
<?php
$query = " SELECT * FROM wmb WHERE lang='$lang' ORDER BY id DESC ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "<a href='dashboard/files/wmb/".$row['link']."' target='_blank'>".$lang_wmb7.$row['date']."</a>";

echo '<hr />';
?>
```

I did research my question and found a similar question

"Embed an MP3 music file onto an image" 
[Embed an MP3 music file onto an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584888/embed-an-mp3-music-file-onto-an-image)

but was not sure how to incorporate it into my existing php file.

I need some advice please.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your hyperlink is opening .mp3 file as a *pure file* directly by browser. That means that you cannot add anything else to your simple hotlink except single .mp3 (or ie .jpg) file.

Buuut... to do what you want to achieve you will need to develop a special page for (dis)playing music & images altogether, ie like play.php.

Hyperlink should look like this..

```
echo '<a href="play.php?song='.$row['link'].'&image='.$row['image'].'" target='_blank'>".$lang_wmb7.$row['date']."</a>";
```

play.php should look like..

```
<html> // and so on.....

            <?php
    $image = $_GET['image']; //ie image of an specific author
    $song = $_GET['row']; // ie somesong.mp3
    echo '<br><br>MY MUSIC PLAYER YEAH<br><br><br>';

    echo '<img src="images/pictures/'.$image.'"><br>
    <audio>check out how this tag works'.$SONG.'</audio>';
            ?>
</html>
```

ps: you can incorporate this into your own file also, but its nicer for this thing to be played by a new tab.

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you.  I understand what you wrote about my existing hyperlink.  I'm going to study what you wrote and try to implement it.  I know I will have followup questions probably in the next day or so.  Thank you so much.  I'm very grateful to you.

Comment: Hi Joem - I need some help. Hyperlink loads the image on new page however audio player is not loading although it selected the correct audio file.  echo "<a href='modules/music/play.php?song=".$row['link'].'&image='.$row['image']."' target='_blank'>".$lang_wmb7.$row['date']."</a>";
echo '<hr />';
Play.php file    <html>  <?php
    $image = $_GET['wmbvog.jpg']; //ie image of an specific author
    $song = $_GET['row']; // ie somesong.mp3
    echo '<img src="pictures/wmbvog.jpg" height="575" width="777"><br>
    <audio>href="dashboard/files/wmb/'.$SONG.'"</audio>';
            ?>  </html>

Comment: The link on the new page is - modules/music/play.php?song=55-0117_ENG.mp3&image=    The image loads correctly and it has selected the correct audio file (55-0117_ENG.mp3) but the player is not loading on top of the image therefore no access to the audio file. Please,  I need your help to figure this out.  Thank you.

Comment: The audio file is located in the root directory of dashboard/files/wmb/

Comment: Hi Joem  I made some changes to the image size (play.php file)  so that I could see the audio player but I cannot figure out why the audio file will not play.    The image and the player load correctly but the mp3 file will not play.
<html>
<body>
            <?php
    $image = $_GET['wmbvog.jpg']; //ie image of an specific author
    $song = $_GET['link']; // ie somesong.mp3
    echo '<img src="pictures/wmbvog.jpg" height="475" width="777"><br>
    <audio controls autoplay> href='dashboard/files/wmb/".$row['link']."'
 </audio>';
            ?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Can anyone offer some assistance here please? Thank you.

Comment: Please, explore how "audio" tag works. IE.<audio src="dashboard/files/wmb/' . $row['link'] . '" controls> Sorry I have no time for further assistance.</audio>. :D